# How to convert the localisation in Android string resources files to Windows Phone 8 resources file?

Tags: android, windows-phone-8, localization, internationalization, windows-phone

I have the localised string file(s) of an internationalised Android app. Now I want to bring the string translations over to a new Windows Phone 8 ("WP8") app without having to manually copy every string individually.

I found several tools that can do iOS -> Android and/or Android -> iOS (e.g. [LocalizedStrings2Android](https://github.com/wrapp/LocalizedStrings2Android), [stringsconvert](http://members.home.nl/bas.de.reuver/files/stringsconvert.html), etc.), but there seems to be no tool out there that can transform the string files Android -> WP8 (or even iOS -> WP8).

Apple's iOS uses files with simple key-value pairs, Android has an XML file, and WP8 uses "XAML" that contains special binding clauses. WP8's format/content differs quite a bit from iOS's and Android's. Is that the reason no tool(s) exist?

I'd appreciate any pointers to existing tools or hints how to best approach this problem.

If you choose to downvote the question please be so kind to leave a comment.

And finally: No, web searches return nothing, unfortunately!

Comment: Probably are.  Consult your nearest search engine.

Comment: BTW I’ve upvoted.
Perfectly valid question.
IMO it’s not about finding a tool, it’s about solving a programming-related problem.

Answer (score 2):

Microsoft Excel.

Open the Android’s strings.xml with it.
It will ask “How would you like to open?” choose “As an XML table”, it’ll message “Excel will create a schema”, press OK.

In Excel, use cut & paste to reorder the columns so the first column is "name" second is "string". You can cut and paste the compete columns by right-clicking on the headers.

Then you’ll be able to copy-paste the whole table, both names and strings, from Excel to the Visual Studio’s *.resx editor. You might have some issues if e.g. you have many names containing spaces, or with values containing newlines, but it still should be much faster then copy all your individual strings.

If you want to automate (e.g. if you have dozens of languages), the .resx format is a simple XML as well. If you know XSLT, the transformation will only take a few lines, if you don't, use any scripting language instead.

Comment: This approach will work nicely as long as the Android XML does not contain any `<string-array>` or `<plurals>` elements. If it _does_ contain these elements an XSLT transformation or a SAX reader/writer could be a better solution, depending on the number of strings.